# ElasticSearch speed issue

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

We are using ElasticSearch for 15M records. The records are split in different indexes sizes where some of the indexes have 1,5 million records.

We have enough RAM 80 GB and the whole index of 60 GB is fitting into the RAM. As response times from ElasticSearch we have the stats that, the query execution took 7ms, but we get the results from ElasticSearch in 300ms. What is wrong here? Where can we search, where our time is going?

ES Settings:

```
2 Nodes on 2 different hosts

Each index has 1 primary shard we have 2 shards each index 

3,762 Total Shards

3,762 Successful Shards

85 Indices

20,347,989 Documents

40.5GB Size
```

[image]

elasticsearch.yml

```
index.cache.field.type: soft

indices.cache.filter.size: 50%

index.fielddata.cache: soft

index.cache.field.expire: 60m

indices.fielddata.cache.size: 50%

indices.fielddata.cache.expire : 60m

index.store.type: mmapfs

transport.tcp.compress: true;

bootstrap.mlockall: true

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.warn: 10s

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.info: 5s

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.debug: 2s

index.search.slowlog.threshold.query.trace: 500ms
```

Example: We have an index for the Country DE and there are 1,5M documents. This index has 2 shards.

Starting of ES:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -Xms32g -Xmx32g -Xss256k -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfile=/var/run/elasticsearch.pid -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -cp :/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/*:/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/* -Des.default.config=/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml -Des.default.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.logs=/var/log/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.work=/tmp/elasticsearch -Des.default.path.conf=/etc/elasticsearch org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
```

OS:

```
24 Cores

80 GB of RAM

60 GB are used

Disk space: 1,2 TB

350 GB used / 780GB free

Disc type: SAS

Mysql is running also on this machine
```

Example Query: search for some City, where we give to ES the location_id:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": {},
    "facets": {
        "location_id": {
            "facet_filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "sponsored": [
                                1,
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "50km",
                            "geo_point": {
                                "lat": -33.42628,
                                "lon": -70.56656
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "terms": {
                "field": "location_facet",
                "all_terms": true,
                "size": 100,
                "script": "doc['geo_point'].empty ? null : ceil(doc['geo_point'].arcDistanceInKm(-33.42628,    -70.56656)) + '|' + doc['location_facet'].value\n + '|' + doc['location_id'].value"
            }
        },
        "company_id": {
            "facet_filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "sponsored": [
                                1,
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "50km",
                            "geo_point": {
                                "lat": -33.42628,
                                "lon": -70.56656
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "terms": {
                            "location_id": [
                                25717
                            ]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "terms": {
                "field": "company_facet",
                "order": "count",
                "script": "doc['company_facet'].value + '|' + doc['company_id'].value"
            }
        },
        "job_type_id": {
            "facet_filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "terms": {
                            "sponsored": [
                                1,
                                0
                            ]
                        }
                    }, {
                        "geo_distance": {
                            "distance": "50km",
                            "geo_point": {
                                "lat": -33.42628,
                                "lon": -70.56656
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "terms": {
                "field": "jobtype_facet",
                "order": "term",
                "all_terms": true
            }
        }
    },
    "filter": {},
    "size": 10,
    "from": 0,
    "explain": false,
    "highlight": {
        "order": "score",
        "require_field_match": false,
        "pre_tags": [
            "<b>"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "</b>"
        ],
        "fields": {
            "description": {
                "type": "fvh",
                "force_source": true,
                "no_match_size": 200,
                "index_options": "offsets",
                "fragment_size": 200,
                "number_of_fragments": 2,
                "matched_fields": [
                    "description",
                    "title"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Response time on this query: > 400ms, which is very slow. We have disabled the facetes as well, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Its difficult to tell like this. You should check the following:

* How is the network latency?
* Is the payload large that it is taking time in network transfer?
* Are you using HTTP? Try the Thrift module as you will be able to take the advantage of lower overhead of TCP and Thrift's compression.

Comment: It would be helpful to know much more about your cluster. How many nodes? How many shards (primary and replica)? What's your JVM settings? CPUs and number of cores? Disk space? Type of disks? Are you measuring CPU and disk performance during queries? Are you inserting at the same time? Where are you getting the 7ms and 300ms timings?

Comment: @vaidik: thanks for the fast response! We don't have any latency issue. Our servers are in a private network. I also test the request from external servers and the download time took only 9ms. The size of the returned document is 47300 bytes. The real problem is coming from ES, because in the response there is the took time returned.

Comment: @John Petrone: thanks for the fast response. I will send you the data you need. I thing this is some settings issue in ES, because we have different indexes with different size in documents, but actual we use the same amount of shards=2. For example the one index has 1,5M rows. Do you thing 2 shards are to less?

Comment: How are you calculating the response time? in one place you say it's 7 ms execution time, in another you say response time is 300ms and in another you say it's over 400 ms. Where are you getting all these data points?

Comment: Answer what @JohnPetrone is asking and it might get easier to find a solution for you. IO could also be a culprit. So monitor your disk performance.

But before all of that, tell us how you are measuring.

Comment: Well I have send you an Screenshot of the ElasticSearch Admin tool. You can see there, this are the internal response times, what ES calculates. We have our own time calculation for each step and at the end, when the result comes to us it takes over 100ms. This what we have found with many test is, that the facetes are taking to much time for request. Additionally there is no option to cache this facetes, because they are in script and GEO facetes.

Comment: I don't see anything in your screenshot that shows a query running in 7ms. In any event, a facet search on 1.5M documents with multiple scripts is going to take some time, so I would not consider 100 ms to 400 ms poor performance. Facets and scripts together are going to be slow -

Comment: +1 for what @JohnPetrone says about scripts and facets. This is something I have experienced myself with facets and scripts. This is because ES is not made for executing scripts. One solution could be that you can store the result of script in the document itself at the time of indexing and then do a term facet on it. This is how I solved my problem and it worked pretty well for me.

Comment: How do you index, and what is your mapping?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad - the question has a good deal of detail in it, but it feels like the slowness could be the result of many things. Since it is 18 months old and both abandoned by the OP and not answered by anyone else, my guess is that it's now not going to get any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

For single points a "geo_bounding_box" filter may be faster than "geo_distance".